# How to implement table sections with core data

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

I am using core data in my iOS app. I have a tableview to show the data from an entity called persons. The entity persons has several attributes, on of them is "date". I would like to create 5 permanent sections in the table view (0.Today, 1.Tomorrow, 2.This week, 3.This month, 4.Upcoming), then I want the data to be shown on each section depending on the date.
I have been searching for this question, but nothing found that could be applied to my app.
I kindly request you to tell me the right way to handle it.

This is my code so far:

```
#import "PersonsTVC.h"
#import "Person.h"

@implementation PersonsTVC
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedPerson;
@synthesize searchResults,titulosseccion;

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Person"; // Put your entity name here
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Person.name = Blah"];

    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstname"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];
}



- (void) viewDidLoad
{



    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}





-(void) viewDidUnload{
    self.searchResults = nil;
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];


}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Perform segue to detail when a SEARCH table cell is touched
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Person Detail Segue" sender:tableView];
    }

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Persons Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    // Configure the cell...
    Person  *person = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        person = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show normal data");
        person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }








    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", person.firstname, person.surname];
    cell.textLabel.text = person.firstname;
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Yellow"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Black"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Black"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Grey"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Grey"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Red"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Blue"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Dark Green"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DarkGreen"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Light Green"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightGreen"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Light Blue"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LightBlue"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Brown"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Brown"];
    }
    if ([person.inRole.color isEqual :@"Dark Orange"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DarkOrange"];



    }

    NSDate *fechasinformat = person.date;
    NSString *fecha0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fechasinformat];


   cell.detailTextLabel.text = fecha0;



    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

        // Delete the person object that was swiped
        Person *personToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", personToDelete.firstname);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:personToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Person Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        NSLog(@"Creating a new person and passing it to PersonDetailTVC");
        Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        personDetailTVC.person = newPerson;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Person Detail Segue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Setting PersonsTVC as a delegate of PersonDetailTVC");
        PersonDetailTVC *personDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        personDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        // Store selected Person in selectedPerson property
        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            self.selectedPerson = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }
        else
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            self.selectedPerson = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        NSLog(@"Passing selected person (%@) to PersonDetailTVC",    self.selectedPerson.firstname);
        personDetailTVC.person = self.selectedPerson;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}

- (void)theSaveButtonOnThePersonDetailTVCWasTapped:(PersonDetailTVC *)controller
{
    // do something here like refreshing the table or whatever

    // close the delegated view
    [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        Person* person = evaluatedObject;
        NSString* firstName = person.firstname;

        //searchText having length < 3 should not be considered
        if (!!searchText && [searchText length] < 3) {
            return YES;
        }

        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [firstName isEqualToString:scope])  {
            return ([firstName rangeOfString:searchText].location != NSNotFound);
        }
        return NO; //if nothing matches
    }]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:@"All"];
    return YES;
}



@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have roughly to do the following:

- Add a first sort descriptor on the `date` attribute to the fetch request.
- Add a *transient* property "sectionIdentifier" to the Person entity,
  and implement a custom getter `- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier`
  to the `Person` managed object subclass, that returns
  "0", "1", "2", "3", or "4", depending on the `date` attribute of the object.
- Set `sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"` in the creation of the fetched results controller.
- Add a `titleForHeaderInSection` method to the table view controller, that
  returns "Today", "Tomorrow", ... depending on the section.

The [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project from the Apple Developer Library also demonstrates how this works.

The sort descriptors would then look like this:

```
// First sort descriptor (required for grouping into sections):
NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
// Second sort descriptor (for the items within each section):
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstname" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortByDate, sortByName]];
```

The getter method for the transient "sectionIdentifier" property would look like
(adapted from the "DateSectionTitles" sample code):

```
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp)
    {
        NSDate *date = self.date;
        // Using pseudo-code here:
        if ("date is from today") {
            tmp = @"0";
        } else if ("date is from tomorrow") {
            tmp = @"1";
        } else ... // and so on ...

        [self setPrimitiveValue:tmp forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

To determine if the date falls on today, tomorrow etc you have to use `NSCalendar`
methods.

The `titleForHeaderInSection` method would be similar to this (untested, as
everything else in this answer):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    NSString *sectionName = [theSection name];
    if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        return @"Today";
    } else if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        return @"Tomorrow";
    } ... // and so on ...
    } else {
        return @"Other";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin R, I have download and tested the sample project you tell me, but I am not able to see how can I use it. I am very sorry, but I am not an expert developer, I am doing the app for myself, to learn how to do things. You propose me to add a first sort descriptor on the date attribute to the fetch request...could you help me to make this step by step, that would not only help me, but other people trying to learn.

Comment: I can understand all steps you have listed, but I don't know exactly hot to implement them. I don't want you to write the code for me, but an example how to do it would be fine and kind from you. Thank you again.

Comment: @mvasco: I have added some more information, I hope that it helps.

Comment: thank you again Martin, I will now try to implement your proposal. You have helped me a lot. I will tell you when done.

Comment: Martin, I am getting errors for "No visible @interface" at following code:  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

Comment: @mvasco: I have updated the answer. (The DateSectionTitles project solves that differently, by declaring a "primitiveSectionIdentifier" property and some "dynamic" declarations in "APLEvent.h".

Comment: OK, thanks. I have updated all declarations on my Person.h and Person.m files. No error for the moment, now I will try to implement the NSCalendars method..I will tell you

Comment: Hello again, I am finished and it is working partially, all results are shown under the "Other" section on the table view, I have tried all possible combinations in the sectionIdentifier method...

Comment: @mvasco: Check if the sectionIdentifier method computes the section number 0, 1, 2, ... correctly.

Comment: Martin, if I am not wrong, with this version of the sectionIdentifier method, all entries had to be shown under the Today section:

Comment: - (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    
            tmp = @"0";
    
            
    [self setPrimitiveValue:tmp forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
   
    return tmp;
}
@end

Comment: and this code in my PersonTVD.m file: - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    
    NSString *sectionName = [theSection name];
    if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        return @"Today";
    } else if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        return @"Tomorrow";
    }  
    return @"Other";
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42077/discussion-between-martin-r-and-mvasco)

Comment: Thank you Martin, and sorry, i have now made the changes you say but the app continues showing only the Other section. Where you able to make it working as expected?

Comment: This is my fetch results controller part:     // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];

Comment: hi I am still working on your proposal and now I have another dummy question. Where should I include the getter and how to call it from the code? THats not clear to me. THe other part of your proposal is clear to me...now after reading a lot of information proposed by other expert users like you..

Comment: you mean in the Person.m class, and when is it call or needed?

Comment: @mvasco: You can add it to the Person class, or to a so-called "class category" for the Person class. - You don't explicitly call that method. It is called from the fetched results controller if you set `sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"` in the creation of the FRC.

Comment: thank you, I will try it in a while...you are very nice and patient to me.

Comment: Have you seen that my question and your answer have been published on an website? http://www.ggkf.com/ios/how-to-implement-table-sections-with-core-data. Any idea about the owner of the site?

Comment: Another question and I think I have completed my code using your proposal. When you write 'NSDate *date = self.date;'Do you mean: NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; ??? I guess this is the right way to obtain the current date....Thank you

Comment: In your proposal, at the getter method, I have to assign a value to the sectionIdentifier property that depends on the comparison of the variable date and the date attribute, but  in your code I don't see how to obtain there the date attribute value, I only see the transient property and the current date [NSDate *date]. Am I missing anything? May be [self willAccessValueForKey:@"dueDate"]? dueDate is the attribute where I store the due date....

Comment: I have done it, I have accomplished all your proposals and it is working as expected...Thank you very much.

Comment: @mvasco: Great, I am glad to hear that!

Comment: you have been a great help to me...first your code seemed magical to me, but now, after reading a lot, it is logical and easy to understand. I am very thankful..