# Sort Elements via NSDate and add to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, sorting, core-data

Before I even start asking my question, I'd like to add a little note - *I'm not asking for code.* I want to explicitly state that now, as some may perceive this question as a request for code. I'm asking for ideas on HOW to achieve this, I don't want someone else to do so for me.

Recently, I've gotten myself into Core Data, and I've been experiencing one unique issue that I'm having major problems solving. I have some objects subclassing `NSManagedObject`, and they have three properties, one of which is relevant to this situation - *dueDate*, which is of the type `NSDate`. 
I've been working to find a way to sort the subclassing objects, and then add then into one of five different sections in the `UITableView`, which include:

1. Today
2. Tomorrow
3. One Week
4. One Month
5. Greater Than One Month

Sorting the elements works with this function:

```
func fetchAssignments() {
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Assignment")

    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults =
    managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
        error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let todayDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

        for item in results {
            let dueDate = item.valueForKey("dueDate") as! NSDate
            println(dueDate)
            let calendarComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay,
                fromDate: todayDate, toDate: dueDate, options: nil)

            println("Months: " + calendarComponents.month.description)
            println("Days: " + calendarComponents.day.description)

            if calendarComponents.month >= 2 || (calendarComponents.month == 1 && calendarComponents.day > 0) {
                println("Greater")
            } else if calendarComponents.month == 1 || calendarComponents.day > 7 {
                println("One Month")
            } else if calendarComponents.day > 1 {
                println("One Week")
            } else if calendarComponents.day == 1 {
                println("Tomorrow")
            } else {
                println("Today")
            }
        }

        println()
        tableView.reloadData()

    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

Currently, this function does not utilize my subclassing object, but that shouldn't have any effect other than the need to cast the value as a `NSDate` object.

My question is, how can I insert this objects into the `UITableView`. I understand this is quite a broad question, but I honestly do not know what else to do. I've tried using multiple arrays, one for each category, but that hasn't worked out to well - if one of the arrays is empty, problems arise. How can I sort these objects so that they can inserted **and** deleted once in the `UITableView`?

Comment: That code looks familiar :)

Comment: Here is a sample project from Apple that demonstrates how to group a table view into sections based on the date: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html. And here is a similar question (in Objective-C): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249098/how-to-implement-table-sections-with-core-data.

Comment: @MartinR It's served me well, I was debating if I should link my CodeReview question but decided against it. :P I'll take a look into Apple's project and what Wain has said, thanks a lot for the continued help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at moving your logic around a little, and at using a fetched results controller to deal with the sectioning.

To use a fetched results controller create a fetch and add a sort descriptor by date. This will be a plain list that you can get working first.

Then, add a transient property to you subclass and there you should return the string for which section the object belongs in (the result can be cached so you aren't recalculating it all the time). Set the name of this transient property as the section name key path on the FRC.

Comment: The transient property for the section identifier can probably not return the section name directly ("Today", "Tomorrow", ...) because that would not sort correctly. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20249349/1187415) I suggested to use a number instead (which is translated to the "real" section name in titleForHeaderInSection).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look into the NSFetchedResultsController class. It's specifically designed to display Core Data into a tableview.

[NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html)

You can add sort descriptors, which will keep your sorted and organized and supports the swipe left to delete functions.  It does a lot of heavy lifting for you when it comes to managing core data in a table view.