# How to recalculate IndexPath for NSFetchedResultsController with records divided into 3 sections: today, future, past?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an entity `Address` and `date` property.

Simple initialization for fetchedResultsController is:

```
private func setupFetchedResultsController() {

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Address>(entityName: "Address")
    let dateDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateDescriptor]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

but the problem is following, because I need to display results like this:

Suppose today is `24.04.2017`

```
TODAY SECTION

A 24.04.2017 
B 24.04.2017

FUTURE SECTION

D 27.04.2017
E 28.04.2017
G 28.04.2017
F 29.04.2017

PAST SECTION

C 17.02.2017
E 19.04.2017
F 20.04.2017
```

What should I do and how, to display results like this?

possible solution is:

```
func recalculatedIndexPath(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    //here need to convert indexPath from fetchedresultsController to the one my table view expects
    //the question is how?
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249098/how-to-implement-table-sections-with-core-data for Objective-C, but the approach is the same in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sectionNameKeyPath`.  Fetches and sort must be based on values that are stored in the database, but the `sectionNameKeyPath` can be based on any property of the object - even one that you created yourself.  So you can add something like -(NSString*)headerName as a property on the `Address` objects.

Here are some things to look out for:

- The `sectionNameKeyPath` is called for EVERY object in the fetchedResultsController.  So the method being called should be fast.  In your case calculating the start time of the current day using a calendar is resource intensive. So I suggest making some global place that caches an NSDate `firstMomentOfCurrentDate`, so the sections can be calculated just use date compares and simple math.
- You should monitor for significant time changes  (`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`) so you can update the table when the date changes and sections need to be reloaded.

Comment: it cannot be like this, the address that today is in today section, tomorrow is in future section...

Comment: So when the date changes you have to invalidate the cached value of `firstMomentOfCurrentDate ` and reload the fetchedResultsController and the tableview.  You should use `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` to do this.